# Firefox 4 и Selenium IDE, или как вернуть Firefox 3.6

Tags: selenium, firefox, ubuntu

Обновил себе firefox, а Selenium IDE для него еще нет. Вернуть назад 3.6 не получается, уже и удалял firefox, и исключал мозиллу из списка репозиториев, и скачивал бинарник 3.6, все равно запускается 4.0.
Что делать не подскажете?

Comment: еще плагин для delicious не работает для 4-й

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, народ, сори, поспешил на хешкодик полезть - достаточно было перезагрузить систему.